# Need to suppress link.no-such-reference for Doc-fx note

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

We use DocFx in our projects. We would like to check for no problems in VSCode but we get the warning link.no-such-reference for DocFx Note formatting which uses square brackets.

Do you support suppression of problems like using:

```
[//]: # (<!-- markdownlint-disable line-length -->)
```

Could not find any documentation about suppressing one problem type once at a single code line.